# Call Twitter Bootstrap Lightbox on page load

Tags: html, css, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I need my twitter bootstrap lightbox to trigger as soon as the HTML page loads, currently I have this in my 'main.js' file:

```
function lightbox(){
    $('#myLightbox').lightbox();
   };
```

Apparently i can use a window.pulse command? My knowledge of jquery is still quite basic.

Here is the html markup for the lightbox:

```
<div id="myLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class='lightbox-content'>
            <img src="path/to/picture.jpg">
            <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>The lightbox is here.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#myLightbox').show();
});
```

That way when your page loads it should your lightbox will show.

Make sure you're referencing jQuery in your HTML page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option needs to be passed into the lightbox method:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#myLightbox').lightbox();
    jQuery('#myLightbox').lightbox('show');
});
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the creation of the lightbox. It wouldn't have been able to show the lightbox until it was created.

Comment: hi, this still isnt working, i can produce an alert so i know the code is going through the function.

Comment: if i remove the document.ready line i am given the modal background from my bootstrap.css?